# Calculating $\int_{0}^{\infty} \sqrt{y}x^{\frac{3}{2}}e^{-\frac{x^3y^3+x^2}{2}} dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, normal-distribution, bivariate-distributions

I am trying to calculate the density of $\frac{Z_1^{\frac{2}{3}}}{Z_2}$,where $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent normal random variables. It boils down to the calculation of this integral.Is there any way to calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \sqrt{y}x^{\frac{3}{2}}e^{-\frac{x^3y^3+x^2}{2}} dx$?
Also,is there any other way to calculate density of,say, $Z_1^2/Z_2^3$

Comment: as long as $y>0$ this integral is hopelessly divergent

Comment: I am extremely sorry,my post had quite a few errors. I have edited it now,the power of e is negative.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%5Bx%5E(3%2F2)Exp%5B-x%5E3-x%5E2%5D,%7Bx,0,inf%7D%5D

OMG!!!

Comment: What is the meaning of $Z_1^{2/3}$ if $Z_1<0$?

Comment: same as $ (-Z_1)^{\frac{2}{3}}$,I think